HEVC video_delay is larger in decoder than demuxer error message
I would like transcode a file with HEVC to a live stream with AVC.  The HEVC demuxer reports many errors:
[hevc @ 0x25a3140] video_delay is larger in decoder than demuxer 
If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to https://streams.videolan.org/upload/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)

This error message was reported as Defect #6019 8 years ago. Around that time, in this post, Jun Zhao suggested a patch to which Michael Niedermayer objected to.  I couldn't find anything more recent.
As requested by the error message, I did send an email to the ffmpeg-devel list but no answer.
The input file is an MPEG-TS (MPTS) and I am selecting only one service. The command line is below. I can upload the file somewhere if needed.
Any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thanks
Danny
ffmpeg -loglevel info \
  -i inputFile.ts \
  -map 0:p:167 -map -0:s \
  -filter_complex [p:167:v]scale=1920x1080 \
  -r 25 \
  -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)' \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 6M -x264-params scenecut=0 -threads 2 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ac 2 \
  -f mpegts -muxrate 8M 'udp://192.168.2.10:5555?overrun_nonfatal=1&pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=10000000&fifo_size=10000000'


ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-ni_quadra --enable-ni_logan --extra-ldflags='-L/mnt/swdevel/Torque/lib3p64 -L/lib' --extra-cflags='-I/mnt/swdevel/Torque/include -I/mnt/swdevel/Torque/ext/extinclude -I/include' --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libsrt --disable-indev=android_camera --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --disable-outdev=xv --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libzvbi --enable-vaapi --enable-libmfx --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=alsa --enable-indev=v4l2 --enable-libsoxr --bindir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/bin64 --datadir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/ext/ffmpeg-tqBuild --docdir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/ext/doc --libdir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/lib3p64 --shlibdir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/lib3p64 --incdir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/ext/extinclude/ffmpeg --mandir=/mnt/swdevel/Torque/ext/ffmpeg-tqBuild --disable-doc --enable-x86asm --extra-ldflags='-lm -ldl -L/lib64 -ldrm' --enable-pthreads --extra-libs=-lpthread --disable-debug --disable-stripping

  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100

